# Validate password follows complexity and length rules

Tags: php, passwords, preg-match

I would like to validate that an entered password follows my complexity and length rules using the preg_math function:

```
if (!preg_match('/(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])/', $password)) {
    $errors[]  = 'Password allows alpha-numerical sumbols and should contain number and letters between 6-24 symbols';
}
```

But this function is not working correctly. As my password **should** contain at least one number (0-9) and one letter (a-z) **or** symbols (,),_,- between 6 and 20 symbols.

How can I write my regular expression?
Thanks!

Comment: Write it as three separate tests; one to test the length, one to test for a number and one to test for letters and symbols. Much saner than cramming it all into one regex.

Comment: While it is sensible to check for a minimum length, i would do without the other tests. They only narrow down the search space, and annoy the users so they choose weaker passwords (like `password2014`).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an entire string.
Use strpos: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$password = "test!";
//Enter characters you want to check for
$characters = "/(!?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])/";
//Split into array to check each character
$chars = str_split($characters);

//Set wrong password by default and check for correct characters
$correctPassword = false;

//Check each character
foreach($chars as $char){
    //If characters have been found, set password as correct
    if (strpos($password, $char))
    {
        $correctPassword = true;
    }
}

//Also check for length, equal or greater then 6, smaller or equal to 20
if ( ($correctPassword) && ( strlen($password) >= 6 )  && ( strlen($password) <= 20 ) )
{
    echo "OK";
}
else
{
    echo "Password Unsafe";
}
```

Hope this helps :)

If this is answer you search for, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add anchors and limit the number of character, here is a way to do the job:

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{6,20}$/', $password)
```